# How to get a USB device Name from its Number

Tags: kernel, hardware, usb-drive, dmesg

One of my (several) USB drives are reporting this error in dmesg

```
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

How do I find out the /dev/sdX name of all my USB devices?

In reverse: How do I find out the USB number of a device, given it's /dev/sdX name?

UPDATE:
Many excellent answers given here. I would expect this information to be in a standard tool like `lsusb`, though sadly it's not (yet). I'm choosing to award @sudodus, as his response best seems to answer getting the Name of All Drives.

ANSWER:

To generate more clear output, I suggest this somewhat longer command

```
find /sys/ -name dev -path '*usb*block*' | grep -v "sd../" | grep -Po "\/usb.*\/sd."
```

Comment: Assuming your system is running udev, does this simple trick (from superuser) ouput what you are looking for ? **for devlink in /dev/disk/by-id/usb*; do readlink -f ${devlink}; done**

Comment: Maybe the output of `find /sys/ -name dev -path '*usb*block*'` can help you.

Comment: @MC68020 It outputs all my USB devices as /dev/sdX, but it doesn't say which number they are. `dmesg` uses USB numbers to report errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing with USB mass storage devices (USB pendrives and USB connected SSDs) in my computer and think the output of

```
find /sys/ -name dev -path '*usb*block*'
```

can help you match the USB number of a device with its `/dev/sdX` name.

---

Another method is to match `lsblk` and `lsusb` command lines and to identify them via 'model/product' and 'serial' tags,

```
lsblk -do name,model,serial,hotplug|grep -e HOTPLUG$ -e 1$

sudo lsusb -v |grep -i -e '^BUS .* Device' -e product -e serial
```

Answer (score 3):

Find this device in sysfs

```
# cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1
```

Find all block devices assigned to it

```
# find . -name dev -path '*block*'
./5-1:1/.../block/sdc/sdc2/dev
./5-1:1/.../block/sdc/dev
./5-1:1/.../block/sdc/sdc1/dev
```

Comment: I was not able to find `/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1`, and did not find `dev` under any of `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*`. I have about 7 USB drives plugged into my system

Comment: how is device detected in dmesg?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid whatever good answer to your question as worded in the title won't help you solve your precise problem since the error you report :

```
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

is the result of a fatal failure from the kernel to correctly identify the said usb device. Therefore the impossibility to attach whatever appropriate driver and consequently populate the /sys tree. Don't look for any /dev/sd* corresponding entry, there just cannot be any!

USB error -110 means "*Timeout expired before the transfer completed*".
The number of possible causes for that is just... immense.
However, considering you write having 7 USB drives plugged into your system, not to mention possibly other usb devices such as keyboard, mouse, webcam... the most probable is that the host cannot provide enough power to the device.

In order to confirm, the best way to proceed is to unplug all your usb devices (not only the drives since, at the end of the day we get no information telling that the associated device is a drive) and plug them one after another while watching your dmesg.
Of course, unless you actually get one particuarily demanding device, you understand that the culprit will not be one device in particular but the cumul of them.